# Bold enumeration in multienum package

Tags: macros, lists

I am trying to bold the enumeration in the `multienum` package. The MWE illustrates what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{multienum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multienumerate}
    \renewcommand{\itemx}[1]{\parbox[t]%
    {\labelwidth}{\hfill{\bfseries\labelname}}\hskip\labelsep%
    \parbox[t]{\remainx}{\raggedright #1}\par}%\smallskip
    \renewcommand{\itemxx}[2]{\parbox[t]%
    {\labelwidth}{\hfill{\bfseries\labelname}}\hskip\labelsep
    \parbox[t]{.5\remainxx}{\raggedright #1}\hfill\parbox[t]%
    {\labelwidth}{\hfill{\bfseries\labelname}}\hskip\labelsep
    \parbox[t]{0.5\remainxx}{\raggedright #2}\smallskip}
    \setlength\hsize{\linewidth}%

        \mitemx{Some random item.}
        \mitemxx{Second}{Third}
    \end{multienumerate}
\end{document}
```

But as you notice, it is not the most pleasant way of doing it if I am to bold locally within the `multienumerate` environment more than once in a document. What I want to achieve are commands like `\boldx`, `\boldxx`, or simply `\boldmultienum` that will ensure that the enumeration is done locally. Thus instead of the above I would have something like

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{multienum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{multienumerate}
            \boldx\boldxx % or \boldenumerate to be more general. Need both cases. 
        \mitemx{Some random item.}
        \mitemxx{Second}{Third}
    \end{multienumerate}
\end{document}
```

Or even something like:

```
\begin{multinenumerate}[label=\bfseries\labelname]
\mitemx{one}
\mitemxx{two}{three}
\end{multienumerate}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's simpler. ;-)

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multienum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{multienumerate}
\renewcommand{\labelname}{%
  \bfseries \csname labelenum\romannumeral\themultienumdepth\endcsname}
\mitemx{Some random item.}
\mitemxx{Second}{Third}
\end{multienumerate}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to make it global, do the `\renewcommand` in the preamble; if you want an environment, do

```
\newenvironment{bmultienumerate}
  {\multienumerate
   \renewcommand{\labelname}{%
     \bfseries \csname labelenum\romannumeral\themultienumdepth\endcsname}}
  {\endmultienumerate}
```

---

A key-value implementation:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{multienum}
\usepackage{keyval}
\makeatletter
\define@key{azemulti}{label}{\def\azemulti@label{#1}}
\def\azemulti@label{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\labelname}{%
  \azemulti@label\@nameuse{labelenum\romannumeral\themultienumdepth}}
\newenvironment{xmultienumerate}[1][]
 {\setkeys{azemulti}{#1}%
  \multienumerate}
 {\endmultienumerate}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{xmultienumerate}
\mitemx{Some random item.}
\mitemxx{Second}{Third}
\end{xmultienumerate}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{xmultienumerate}[label=\bfseries]
\mitemx{Some random item.}
\mitemxx{Second}{Third}
\end{xmultienumerate}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried to do this but I placed the `\bfseries` within `\csname \endcsname`. Can we do it with the key value feature?

Comment: Are there commands similar to `\romannumeral` that behave like `\alph` counter?

Comment: @azetina The `\romannumeral` command here is not for setting the output. Please, don't pile up questions in comments.

Comment: My apologies. I will avoid this in future comments.